# Combine SQL columns using case when appearing null

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to combine columns so that they will all display as one column. Problem is that if a row has one column that is null, then the whole row appears as null. I have tried using a `CASE` statement to get this done. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    a.AddressID,
    CASE
    WHEN a.Address IS NULL
    AND a.Address2 IS NULL THEN
        a.City + ' ' + a.State + ' ' + a.Country + ' ' + a.Zip
    WHEN a.Address2 IS NULL THEN
        a.Address + ' ' + a.City + ' ' + a.State + ' ' + a.Country + ' ' + a.Zip
    WHEN a.Zip IS NULL THEN
        a.Address + ' ' + a.Address2 + ' ' + a.City + ' ' + a.State + ' ' + a.Country
    WHEN a.City IS NULL
    AND a.Address2 IS NULL
    AND a.State IS NULL
    AND a.Country IS NULL
    AND a.Zip IS NULL THEN
        a.Address
    WHEN a.Address IS NULL
    AND a.Address2 IS NULL
    AND a.State IS NULL
    AND a.Zip IS NULL THEN
        a.City + ' ' + a.Country
    WHEN a.State IS NULL THEN
        a.Address + ' ' + a.Address2 + ' ' + a.City + ' ' + a.Country + ' ' + a.Zip
    WHEN a.City IS NULL
    AND a.Zip IS NULL THEN
        a.Address + ' ' + a.Address2 + ' ' + a.State + ' ' + a.Country
    WHEN a.Address IS NULL
    AND a.Address2 IS NULL
    AND a.City IS NULL
    AND a.Zip IS NULL THEN
        a.State + ' ' + a.Country
    WHEN a.State IS NULL
    AND a.Zip IS NULL THEN
        a.Address + ' ' + a.Address2 + ' ' + a.City + ' ' + a.Country
    WHEN a.Address IS NULL
    AND a.Address2 IS NULL
    AND a.City IS NULL THEN
        a.State + ' ' + a.Country + ' ' + a.Zip
    WHEN a.Address2 IS NULL
    AND a.State IS NULL THEN
        a.Address + ' ' + a.City + ' ' + a.Country + ' ' + a.Zip
    WHEN a.Address2 IS NULL
    AND a.Zip IS NULL THEN
        a.Address + ' ' + a.City + ' ' + a.State + ' ' + a.Country
    ELSE
        a.Address + ' ' + a.Address2 + ' ' + a.City + ' ' + a.State + ' ' + a.Country + ' ' + a.Zip
    END AS FullAddress
FROM
    Addresses a `
```

My end goal with this is to populate a drop down list in ASP.NET. If anyone knows of another way to get the rows to return null when only one column is null then, then please let me know. I am willing to take another approach. Also, there are way too many rows to go and fix each row so that each row has a value for each column. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The NULL behavior is exactly what it should do. Anytime you concatenate a NULL into a string the result is NULL. It is not at all clear what this massive case expression is trying to do but I suspect you could greatly simplify it with the use of ISNULL around your columns instead.

Comment: Is this mysql or sqlserver? They are not the same thing.

Comment: `Nullif` for one or `coalesce` if multiple possibilities to change null values to  empty string.

Comment: `coalesce(firstChoice, secondChoice, thirdChoice, allelseFailsSomeDefaultValueHere)`

Comment: The end result is a column that displays the Full Address. It will not display the Full Address if a row has a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `IsNull()` and `NULLIF()` function you can achieve your desire output.

Try this

```
SELECT  a.AddressID,
        ISNULL(NULLIF(a.Address + ' ', ''), '') + 
        ISNULL(NULLIF(a.Address2 + ' ', ''), '') +
        ISNULL(NULLIF(a.City + ' ', ''), '') + 
        ISNULL(NULLIF(a.State + ' ', ''), '') + 
        ISNULL(NULLIF(a.Country + ' ', ''), '') + 
        ISNULL(NULLIF(a.Zip, ''), '') AS FullAddress
    FROM
        Addresses a
```

One more thing, If you are using SQL Server 2012 and above then you can use `CONCAT()` function. For that I have written one blog post in my blog - [krishnrajrana.wordpress.com](https://krishnrajrana.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/introduction-to-new-concat-function-in-sql-server-2012/)

Comment: @bds89: Glad to help you... :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the existence of the extra space when null is a big deal? If so then use the IsNull(NullIf( approach.

```
SELECT
    a.AddressID, 
    coalesce(a.Address, ' ') + ' ' + 
    coalesce(a.Address2, ' ') + ' ' + 
    coalesce(a.State, ' ') + ' ' + 
    coalesce(a.Country, ' ') + ' ' + 
    coalesce(a.Zip, '') as FullAddress
FROM Addresses a
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to use coalesce:

```
Select a.AddressID
    , RTRIM(
        coalesce(a.Address+' ', '')
        + coalesce(a.Address2+' ', '')
        + coalesce(a.City+' ', '')
        + coalesce(a.State+' ', '')
        + coalesce(a.Country+' ', '')
        + coalesce(a.Zip+' ', '')
    )
From Addresses a;
```

It will add 1 space after each not null value only and with only 1 space between values.

RTRIM remove the space at the end if the last value(s) is null.

**Sample:**

```
Select '-'+RTRIM(
        coalesce(x+' ', '')
        + coalesce(y+' ', '')
        + coalesce(z+' ', '')
    )+'-'
From (values
    ('a', 'b', 'c')
    , ('a', null, 'c')
    , ('a', 'b', null)
) as v(x, y, z)
```

**Sample output:**

```
-a b c-
-a c-
-a b-
```